# Two hosts of different subnets connected to switch

Tags: switch

Two host of different subnets, let it be A - 10.1.2.1/24 and B - 10.1.3.1/24 be connect to the same switch S. 
Can they communicate?

So as far I understand:

- A sends a packets with IP of B
- S receives it and compare it with    values in Stored Address Table
  else broadcasts it.
- B receives the    packets, check the IP and accepts it.

Am I right?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, you are incorrect.

Ron makes a good point, you didn't provide a subnet mask, so if we were to assume the classful mask, the 10.x.x.x address would have a 255.0.0.0 mask, which would actually put the two hosts on the same network.  If that is the case, they would have no problem communicating.

However, given the nature of your question, I imagine you intended for each of these hosts to use a smaller mask -- we'll go ahead and use 255.255.255.0, which puts both hosts in two different subnets.

That being said, the heart of what you are missing lies in forgetting about [**ARP** (Address Resolution Protocol)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPi5Nvxaosw).  Specifically, in whom HostA decides to ARP for.  Let me explain...

Before any host puts any packet on the wire, the first thing it does is determine whether the destination IP is on its own network, or on a foreign network.  Let's run through it from the perspective of Host A.

Host A know its IP (10.1.2.1), and its Subnet Mask (/24, or 255.255.255.0).  With a little [subnetting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWZ-MHIhqjM&list=PLIFyRwBY_4bQUE4IB5c4VPRyDoLgOdExE), HostA determines that its network spans all the IP addresses in the range of 10.1.2.0 through 10.1.2.255.  *(We'll leave out details of the NetID and BroadcastIP, since for the moment they aren't relevant)*

Host A also knows its destination IP is 10.1.3.1, which falls *outside* of the range of IP addresses within Host A's own network.  As such, Host A would would come to the conclusion that the destination IP 10.1.3.1 is on a foreign network, and Host A could only reach a foreign network by speaking through a Router.  Or more specifically, through HostA's *default gateway*.

If HostA isn't configured with a Default Gateway at this point, then the process ends here with a general failure.  HostA can not speak to HostB.

If HostA *is* configured with a Default Gateway, it would send out an ARP Request (which is itself a Broadcast frame), asking for the MAC address of its default gateway --  **NOT** the MAC address of the final destination IP.

The switch, having received the broadcast frame would flood the packet out all interfaces, to include the one HostB is connected to.  HostB would indeed receive the packet, *but* since the ARP is looking for the Default Gateway's MAC address *(and not the MAC address of HostB)*, HostB would simply drop and ignore the ARP Request, without ever sending any sort of response.

HostA, then, would never receive a MAC address for its default gateway, and would therefore be unable to encapsulate the Layer 3 Packet with a Layer 2 header.  The packet would fail there.

You can see the ARP process illustrated in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPi5Nvxaosw).

---

That said, although somewhat unrelated to your question, I did want to speak to something you said.  This may be terminology nuance, but I just want to make sure it is communicated.  A switch only does two things:  [**forwards** frame for which it know the destination MAC address, or **flood** frames for which it doesn't know the destination MAC address](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/packet-traveling/host-to-host-through-a-switch/#switch-functions).  *A switch never broadcasts*.

A **[broadcast](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/packet-traveling/host-to-host-through-a-switch/#broadcasts)** is a frame who's destination MAC address is `ffff.ffff.ffff`.  This is a specially reserved MAC address, specifically designed for broadcast frames.  When a switch encounters a frame destined to **ffff.ffff.ffff**, its behavior is to always **flood** that frame.

You could look at it like this, since **ffff.ffff.ffff** is a reserved MAC address, it is un-learn-able by the switch.  Therefore, whenever a switch receives something destined to ffff.ffff.ffff, it is forced to flood it out all ports in the VLAN that the frame was originally received in.

Comment: There are edge cases to this answer... hosts can have either no gateway, or their own address configured as their gateway address.  This causes the host to ARP for all addresses and proxy-arp enabled routers with a route (even default route) to the destination will reply with their own mac-address.

Comment: There are edge cases for just about any answer/situation.  I didn't think going into some of them here would be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If they are under /16 Subnet. For /24 subnet, you need router.

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining it more. For instance, explain why it works with `/16`, but `/24 needs a router.

Answer (score 0):

If host A and B are on different networks or subnets and connected to the same switch I believe that they can communicate through the default gateway.

Comment: A gateway address must be in the same network as the address configured on a host. Since the gateway address is the address used to _send traffic off the network_, it must be in the same network as the sending host, otherwise the host would need a gateway to get to the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the switch is connected to a router that knows how to route between these 2 subnets.

Comment: Layer 3 switch does not required separate router